# Is there a way to have different facebook accounts sync'd on different computers in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-people-app

I have a Windows-8 laptop for work.  I just bought one for my wife.  We share the same Windows Live Account but have different Facebook accounts.  Is there a way to have different Facebook accounts linked on different computers for the same Windows Live account?

Comment: Why not get your own Live accounts?  Or share a Facebook account?

Comment: @techie007 sharing Facebook accounts isn't a possibility. I guess I could create a different Window's Live account, but was hoping not to.  We share the same Google account for our android phones which is great because we can share apps that have been purchased...  If she has a different live account, I'm guessing we won't be able to share apps as well?